# Set alignment programmatically in QVBoxLayout not working

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to change the alignment of a button in a vertical layout with setAlignment.
It works if i call setAlignment immediately or if I call it with a timeout equal with 0 or small (~10).
If I make the timeout 200 for example it doesn't work.
It also doesn't work if I press button3.

This problem doesn't appear in a horizontal layout.
Might be a bug?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import  Qt, QTimer
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()

layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
button1 = QPushButton('button1')
button2 = QPushButton('button2')
button3 = QPushButton('Push to align button1')

layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
layout.addWidget(button3)

#layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignTop) #works

timeout = 200
QTimer.singleShot(timeout, lambda: layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignTop))
button3.clicked.connect(lambda: layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignTop))
window.resize(200, 600)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

Ok I solved it. I had to make button1 to expand vertically. But because I don't want it to expand vertically, I changed it in the slot and than change it back to preferred after applying the new alignment.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import  Qt, QTimer
app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()

layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
button1 = QPushButton('button1')
button2 = QPushButton('button2')
button3 = QPushButton('Push to align button1')

layout.addWidget(button1)
layout.addWidget(button2)
layout.addWidget(button3)

def align():
    button1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignTop)
    button1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)

button3.clicked.connect(align)
window.resize(200, 600)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: It seems a bug indeed, I'd suggest you to report it. In the meantime, you could work around it by adding again the widget with the `alignment` argument: `layout.insertWidget(0, button1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)`. For dynamic purposes, you can get the "current" index with `layout.indexOf(widget)`.

Comment: The `setAlignment` call will work if a non-zero flag is explictly set first.

Comment: @musicamante Another issue is that the [docs claim](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) that "the default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell" - which is clearly false. In fact, there doesn't seem to be *any* combination of flags which can reproduce the default state. OTOH, if the alignment is set to zero after being set to some other flag *first*, then the widget *will* fill the entire cell.

Comment: @ekhumoro Uhm, I'm not sure I'm following. Are you referring to the misalignment of the other two buttons (to the bottom) when the first is alignment is set at startup? It seems indeed that there are some issues when changing the alignment on runtime, especially for widgets that have size restraints (like push button): in fact, if the `AlignTop` flag is set on startup and then reset with `Qt.Alignment(0)`, I cannot revert to the default behavior (with all buttons equally sharing vertical space).

Comment: @musicamante No. When there is no initial alignment set, the widgets *do not* fill their cells (as wrongly claimed in the docs). However, if an alignment **is** set initially, and then *reset* later to zero, the widgets **do** to fill their cells (and expand when resizing). I suggest you try with the OPs example, if you can't see what I mean.  What I'm getting at, is that the default zero-state is not the same as the explicitly set zero-state.

Comment: @ekhumoro I always intended that reference as to "fills the entire cell [assuming its size policy and constraints allow it]", but, yes, it's an imprecise definition. Actually, the behavior I now see when resetting the alignment (from the startup `Qt.AlignTop` to the later, explicit `Qt.Alignment(0)`) is wrong in my opinion, since it overrides the `Fixed` vertical size policy of the button.

Comment: @musicamante Yes  I know but I wanted to change it as an option. I also tried to call invalidate() on the layout. How do I report it?

Comment: @badnn1 https://bugreports.qt.io/

Comment: @musicamante Okay. But I didn't intend to express an opinion about what *should* happen (which is a separate concern). I was simply noting the inconsistency in behaviour.

Comment: @badnn1 It's unclear from your question whether you're aware that setting the alignment to a *different* value will work as expected (because your example code only uses `AlignTop`). That is, if you do e.g. `layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignCenter)` *first*, and then call `layout.setAlignment(button1, Qt.AlignTop)` later in a slot, it will work.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes I am but at the beginning the button has no alignment. I don't want to force it to Qt.AlignCenter. What is interesting is that in a QHBoxLayout this problem doesn't appear and I can set the alignment to AlignLeft even if at the beginning the alignment is Qt.Alignment(0).

Comment: @ekhumoro OK I figured it out just when I checked the horizontal layout. QPushButton expands horizontally but not vertically. If i make it to expand vertically button1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding) it reacts to the change of alignment.

Comment: @badnn1 A cleaner solution is to call `button1.updateGeometry()` after setting the alignment.